# Can I tell Windows search not to treat my request as a partial request?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

Using Windows Search, I would like to find my DLL, called Application.dll. However, there are some files, called Application.dll.config, which are also shown. In order to find the dll files, I type `file:Application.dll`, but this also shows the `*.config` files.

Is there a way to ask Windows Search to look for `Application.dll` and not for every file, containing `Application.dll` (like an exact search)?

I'm working with Windows 10, Version 21H2 (OS build 19044.1889), according to `WinVer` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this search syntax : `name:=Application.dll`

This will search for an exact match.

References :

- [Advanced Query Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference)
- [Must-Know and Useful File Explorer Search Syntax Commands](https://windowsloop.com/useful-file-explorer-search-syntax-commands/)

Note that there exist third-party products that are much more
efficient and versatile than Windows Search. Perhaps the best is
the free
[Everything of voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/).